# Issue using displaying Image with NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6

I am very new to xcode and I am playing around with image arrays and NSMutableArray. When I run the code below it just print out the names of the image for example "image1.png". Any tips to fix this problem would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
- (NSMutableArray*)restaurantArray;
{
    if (_restaurantArray == nil) {
        _restaurantArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        @"image1.png",
                        @"image2.png",
                        @"image3.png",
                        nil];
    }

    return _restaurantArray;
}


-(NSString*) randomRestaurant
{
    int random = arc4random_uniform(self.restaurantArray.count);
    return [self.restaurantArray objectAtIndex:random];
}
```

Comment: This looks it randomly gives you a filename, but how are you trying to display the image ?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in this way also.

```
- (NSMutableArray*)restaurantArray;
```

{

```
if (_restaurantArray == nil) {
    _restaurantArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"],
                        nil];
}

return _restaurantArray;
```

}

Comment: this is the correct way to allocate image files into arrays. 
[UIImage imageNamed :@"imagename.extension"];

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?:

```
NSString *imageName = [self randomRestaurant];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageName:imageName];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the image then do this:

Suppose you have an imageview name imgView,

```
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self randomRestaurant]];
```

Or, if you just want the image, then call this:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:[self randomRestaurant]];
```

In you given code, you are just returning the name of the image, not the actual image. If you want an array of image then you can do it by this way:

```
-(NSMutableArray*) restaurantArray;
{
    if (_restaurantArray == nil) {
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"];
        UIImage *img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"];
        UIImage *img2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"];

        _restaurantArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        img,
                        img1,
                        img2,
                        nil];
    }
    return _restaurantArray;
}

-(UIImage*) randomRestaurant
{
    int random = arc4random_uniform(self.restaurantArray.count);

    return [self.restaurantArray objectAtIndex:random];
}
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: hmm okay,when I do this I get a few errors saying "use of undeclared identifier 'img'"

Comment: Error says it, You have to declare img first. I think you are not declaring that variable.

Comment: but how exactly do I do that? Am I not doing that in that statement?

Comment: Can you post the function where you are getting this error?

Comment: I don't see anything that will give compilation error. Post your code.